# GC in .NET 4.0 not affecting Working Set in task manager

Tags: memory-management, .net-4.0, garbage-collection, taskmanager, clr4.0

OK, just to be clear, I understand that the Task Manager is never a good way to monitor memory consumption of a program.  Now that I've cleared the air...

I've used SciTech's .Net memory profiler for a while now, but almost exclusively on the .Net 3.5 version of our app.  Typically, I'd run an operation, collect a baseline snapshot, run the operation again and collect a comparison snapshot and attack leaks from there.  Generally, the task manager would mimic the rise and fall of memory (within a range of accuracy and within a certain period of time).

In our .net 4.0 app, our testing department reported a memory when performing a certain set of operations (which I'll call operation A).  Within the profiler, I'd see a sizable change of live bytes (usually denoting a leak).  If I immediately collect another snapshot, the memory is reclaimed (regardless of how long I waited to collect the initial comparison snapshot).  I thought the finalizer might be getting stuck so I manually injected the following calls:

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
GC.Collect();
```

When I do that, I don't see the initial leak in the profiler, but my working set in the Task Manager is still ridiculously high (operation A involves loading images).  I thought the issue might be a stuck finalizer (and that SciTech was able to do some voodoo magic when the profiler collects its snapshots), but for all the hours I spent using WinDbg and MDbg, I couldn't ever find anything that suggested the finalizer was getting stuck.  If I just let my app sit for hours, the memory in the working set would never reduce.  However, if I proceeded to perform other operations, the memory would drop substantially at random points.

**MY QUESTION**
I know the GC changed substantially with CLR 4.0, but did it affect how the OS sees allocated memory?  My computer has 12 GB RAM, so when I run my app and ramp up my memory usage, I still have TONS free so I'm hypothesizing that it just doesn't care to reduce what it's already allocated (as portrayed in the Task Manager), even if the memory has been "collected".  When I run this same operation on a machine with 1GB RAM, I never get an out of memory exception, suggesting that I'm really not leaking memory (which is what the profiler also suggests).

The only reason I care what the Task Manager shows because it's how our customers monitor our memory usage.  If there is a change in the GC that would affect this, I just want to be able to show them documentation that says it's Microsoft's fault, not ours :)

*In my due diligence, I've searched a bunch of other SO threads for an answer, but all I've found are articles about the concurrency of the generational cleanup and other unrelated, yet useful, facts.*

Answer (score 0):

You cannot expect to see changes in the use of managed heap immediately reflected in process memory. The CLR essentially acts as a memory manager on behalf of your application, so it allocates and frees segments as needed. As allocating and freeing segments is an expensive operation the CLR tries to optimize this. It will typically not free an empty segment immediately as it could be used to serve new managed allocations. If you want to monitor managed memory usage, you should rely on the .NET specific counters for this.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I understand and agree with your answer (and have emphatically tried to convince others that the task manager is never an accurate way to gauge memory usage). Regardless, customers still use it.  My point is, with CLR 3.5 and before, I would at least see somewhat predictable fluctuation in what the task manager would show.  Now, memory will increase when expected, but isn't reduced (and won't be unless I perform other random operations).  I'm not saying this means I have a leak.  I'm just wondering if something changed in CLR 4 that would've affected this.

Comment: Task manager is fine for process memory, but managed memory is only a part of the total process memory and the CLR is free to do whatever it needs to in order to optimize how the process allocates/frees memory needed for the managed heap.

Comment: Again, good point, but my question is whether something changed between CLR 3.5 and 4.0 that would affect this perception.  I would love to explain the nuances of managed memory to customers, but they don't seem to care.  They do, however, pay us money and I need to make sure they're happy :)

Comment: The key here is that the CLR handles when to allocate/free memory at the OS level. It does so based on a number of heuristics (whether those changed between 3.5 and 4 I don't know). In my experience the CLR holds on to segements longer on systems with ample memory avaiable.